# Do large-scale modes of variability (like NAM/SAM/ENSO) exist in the ocean?

Tags: ocean, enso

Large-scale patterns of climate variability can be explained at this [Annular Modes Website](http://www.atmos.colostate.edu/ao/introduction.html).

If so, have they been characterized by EOF analysis in the same way that the annular modes in the atmosphere have been characterized? Where would be able to find this?

Comment: Could you be more precise in what exactly you mean by *annular modes*?  The short answer is *yes*, but that might not be a satisfactory one.

Comment: ENSO *is* a large scale variability in the ocean (to which the atmosphere responds)

Comment: The separation between ocean and atmosphere when we talk about large-scale modes of variability is difficult as shown by Casey's comment. ENSO affects both the ocean and the atmosphere and it is better studied as a coupled mode of variability.

Answer (score 6):

The large scale modes of variability present in the atmosphere are also found in the ocean. There is a strong feedback between the two systems with wind, heat flux and atmospheric pressure modifying ocean surface conditions and with parameters such as sea surface temperature altering atmospheric conditions.

A lot of studies have explored teleconnections in the ocean looking for instance at the EOFs of sea surface temperature. A good compilation of different atmospheric and oceanic time series and references can be found in [Climate Indices: Monthly Atmospheric and Ocean Time Series](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/climateindices/list/).